# Добавить данные в одно поле в Cloud Firestore в Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Я новичок в андроид разработке. У меня вопрос. Можно ли добавлять данные в одно поле с разными названиями в Cloud Firestore в Android Studio? Например пользователь вводит свое имя и выбирает район в Spinner-е и нажимает "Добавить". Данные должны попасть в одну коллекцию и поле в Cloud Firestore. В коде ниже указан способ добавления данных в разные коллекции:

```
 btn_setData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Map<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, String> spinnerMap = new HashMap<>();

            nameMap.put("name", et_setName.getText().toString());
            spinnerMap.put("district", sp_selectDistrict.getSelectedItem().toString());

            mFirestore.collection("users").document().set(nameMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(SelectLocationActivity.this, "Запись прошла успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(SelectLocationActivity.this, "Запись не удалась", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            mFirestore.collection("users_district").document().set(spinnerMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(SelectLocationActivity.this, "Запись прошла успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Можно ли объединить эти два действия? Или с типом "Object" в базе при создании поле. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. В обработчике, вместо

```
Map <String, String>
```

указываем что хотим поместить параметры в тип object

```
Map<String, Object>
```

в Cloud Firestore. Определяем один HashMap и вставляем туда et_setName, sp_selectDistrict (EditText, Spinner):

```
 btn_setData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Map<String, Object> userDataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            userDataMap.put("name", et_setName.getText().toString());
            userDataMap.put("district", sp_selectDistrict.getSelectedItem().toString());
            mFirestore.collection("user_data").document().set(userDataMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(SelectLocationActivity.this, "Запись прошла успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(SelectLocationActivity.this, "Запись не удалась", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]